# Cannot remove administrator access from Azure AD account

Tags: administrator, windows-11, microsoft-account, azure-activedirectory

I received a new company laptop and selected "Work or School" account in the initial setup, typed in my work email address. Everything set up smoothly for the AzureAD/username account except I don't want my account to be an administrator account. I was able to remove it from local administrator group by using

net localgroup administrators azuread\username /delete

However, although it succeeded in removing my account from local administrators group, it still shows as some kind of administrator as shown in the screenshot. The option to change to standard account is greyed out.

[image]

Could anyone please enlighten me about what is the difference between local administrator group and this administrator role in Windows?

Also, what is the best way to remove administrator access from my AzureAD/username account? Or is it impossible?

Comment: This is likely a question for your company. But you need an Admin account for fixing things, so set up a standard user account for yourself and use that as your working account.

Comment: Is the account in *any* local groups?

Comment: The only thing your account did was remove the Azure Active Directory domain user from the local Administrator group on the machine.  You will need to get your AZ AD Administrator to change your account for you.  What you want cannot be done with an unelevated account. I would argue if you are NOT part of the local administrator group, you are only part of the Users group on the machine, and thus your account type is already what you want it to be.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound . I am part of the admin group. This account was originally in the local admin group but even after removing it from admin group it still had admin access on the computer. I don't know if we even have an Azure AD Administrator. I think it may be best to just configure the computer as a personal computer (not work computer) because then we are just working with local accounts and don't have any Azure AD accounts.

Comment: Although if I could get access to Azure AD dashboard or admin panel, then it would certainly be convenient to change the account to a standard user from there.

Comment: @Philip - So ask your Administrator if you are an Administrator.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. I signed into Azure AD portal where I am the global administrator. The users in the company generally have no assigned roles, no administrative roles. So I don't see any place to get rid of their administrative access on their Azure AD joined Windows device. Do you know where in the GUI I can take away their admin rights on their own device?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is usually possible to remove administrative access from Azure AD account by doing

```
net localgroup administrators azuread\username /delete
```

I confirmed it works on a user's computer.

However for some strange reason it was not working on my particular computer. Best to just create a local account and don't azure ad join.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).